# Не запускается rabbitmq-server

Tags: rabbitmq

```
Starting broker...
BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,
                       {rabbitmq_management_agent,
                        {{shutdown,
                          {failed_to_start_child,rabbit_mgmt_agent_sup,
                           {shutdown,
                            {failed_to_start_child,
                             rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,
                             {badarg,
                              [{erlang,list_to_binary,
                                [[99,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,1045,1074,
                                  1075,1077,1085,1080,1081,47,65,112,112,68,
                                  97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,
                                  82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,
                                  114,97,98,98,105,116,64,76,65,80,84,79,80,
                                  45,56,86,72,86,86,80,75,73,46,108,111,103]],
                                [{error_info,#{module => erl_erts_errors}}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-i/2-lc$^0/1-0-',
                                1,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,276}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-i/2-lc$^0/1-0-',
                                1,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,276}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,i,2,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,276}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,infos,3,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,226}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,emit_update,1,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,425}]},
                               {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,init,1,
                                [{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},
                                 {line,401}]},
                               {gen_server,init_it,2,
                                [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,848}]}]}}}}},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_agent_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}}

{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{rabbitmq_management_agent,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,rabbit_mgmt_agent_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_binary,[[99,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,1045,1074,1075,1077,1085,1080,1081,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,114,97,98,98,105,116,64,76,65,80,84,79,80,45,56,86,72,86,86,80,75,73,46,108,111,103]],[{error_info,#{module=>erl_erts_errors}}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-i/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,276}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-i/2-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,276}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,i,2,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,276}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,infos,3,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,226}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,emit_update,1,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,425}]},{rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,init,1,[{file,"rabbit_mgmt_external_stats.erl"},{line,401}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,848}]}]}}}}},{rabbit_mgmt_agent_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({error,{rabbitmq_management_agent,{{shutdown,{_}},{rabbit_mgmt_agent_app,start,[_]}}}})

Crash dump is being written to: c:/Users/┼тухэшщ/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/erl_crash.dump...done
```

После запуска rabbitmq-server выдаёт такую портянку... пытался и через ехе. устанавливать и вручную.

Comment: Похоже, какой-то дефект в RabbitMQ. Попробуйте обновиться до последней версии или сообщите об ошибке разработчикам. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues

Comment: Я уже несколько раз скачивал последнюю версию и exe файл и zip распаковывал, всё одно и то же...